# create output via speaker even with headphone plugged in?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32com, win32gui

Using MMSystem API or waveOut, how can you make the speaker create audible output even when a headphone is plugged in?

In other words, how can you make output audible on both devices at the same time?

thx
Chris

Comment: Odd - you keep asking questions though not a single answer has been accepted as correct.....

Comment: This is entirely down to the hardware. The internal speaker is normally electrically disconnected when an external speaker/headphone is plugged in.

Comment: +1 for Deanna - fix it with a soldering iron.

Answer (score 0):

**Luckily** for your users, the speaker is disabled in hardware (not software) as soon as there's a jack in the headphone socket. Which means there's no way for you to circumvent this.

I've checked 4 computers in our office: only one has a jumper on its mainboard where you can keep both enabled. The other three don't have such a jumper and the speaker is disabled automatically if there's something in the headphone plug.

Comment: Piece of wire, soldering iron, job done.  Not everything has to be done in software!

Comment: Hello.

The reason why I ask it is that Skype allows you to select "Ring on all devices".
Very handy when 'by accident" you have the headphone plugged in but not on your head while talking to a colleague for example.
If an incoming call comes in you won't hear it without that option. With "Ring on all devices" active you' won't miss a thing.

Comment: So my question is: if it is possible with Skype, how do they do it?
Since just installing Skype without having to solder anything on any computer, surely they implement via software. But how?

I want to implement the same functionality in my application

thanks

Comment: FYI: that skype-feature doesn't work on my machines, neither on my laptop nor on my desktop. If the headphones are plugged in, then sound comes *only* from there, nowhere else.